# Muetexes in perl & MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux, perl, unix, locking

I am trying to insure that only one instance of a perl script can run at one time. The script performs some kind of db_operation depending on the parameters passed in. The script does not necessarily live in one place or on one machine, and possibly multiple OSs. Though the file system is automounted across the various machines.

My first aproach was to just create a .lock file,  and do the following:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Fcntl qw(:DEFAULT :flock);
...
open(FILE,">>",$lockFilePath);
flock(FILE,LOCK_EX) or die("Could not lock ");
do_something();
flock(FILE,LOCK_UN) or die("Could not unlock ");
close(FILE);
```

but I keep getting the following errors:

```
Bareword "LOCK_EX" not allowed while "strict subs" in use
Bareword "LOCK_UN" not allowed while "strict subs" in use
```

So I am looking for another way to approach the problem. Locking the DB itself is also not practical since the db could be used by other scripts(which is acceptable), I am just trying to prevent this script from running. And locking a table for write is not practical, since my script is not aware of what table the operation is taking place, it just launches another perl script supplied as a parameter.

I am thinking of adding a table to the db, with just one value, and to use that as a muetex, but I don't know how practical/reliable that is(a lot of red flags go up in my head). I have a DBI connection to a db that this script useses.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds to me like your sub-scripts need to do their own locking, since your runner script doesn't know whether it's safe to run multiple copies or not.

Comment: Very odd that you get that error. Make sure that `use Fcntl qw(:flock);` is in effect for the block where you use it. Try adding it directly above the `flock` calls. You can also try using the values of those constants, see [flock](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/flock.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Bareword` error you are getting sounds like you've done something in that "..." to confuse Perl with regard to the imported Fcntl constants. There's nothing wrong with using those constants like that. You might try something like `LOCK_UN()` to see what error that gets you.

If you are using MySQL, you can use the `GET_LOCK()` and `RELEASE_LOCK()` mechanism. It works reasonably well for cases like this:

```
SELECT GET_LOCK("script_lock");
```

and then when you are finished:

```
SELECT RELEASE_LOCK("script_lock");
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/miscellaneous-functions.html for details.

Comment: or `&LOCK_EX`, `&LOCK_UN`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to avoid the file locking; from what I remember it's notoriously unreliable on non-local filesystems.  Your better bet is to just use the existence of the file itself to the indicator that the script is already running (similar to a UNIX PID file)  Granted, this won't be 100% reliable but should work reasonably reliably with very low overhead, provided the script isn't getting invoked incessantly.

If you need better reliability than that, using the database for the mutex is a good solution.